What does legacy mode refer to when dual booting an iMac?
I have a 2008 iMac that has MacOS and Linux Mint installed. When searching for a solution to a problem I have seen it stated that I need to boot in 'legacy' mode. What does this mean? Does it refer to old PC BIOS? Such a BIOS never existed on this iMac, it was always EFI.
I installed using the Mint installer as far as I remember and I think it is using EFI. If I run efibootmgr I get the following:
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,04202405-8589-4b15-b2c7-f72a95053a68,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0081* Mac OS X  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,5f1185c2-ae3c-4590-99ba-c57db72f5442,0x64028,0xcbee240)
BootFFFF*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,5f1185c2-ae3c-4590-99ba-c57db72f5442,0x64028,0x79fc5c8)/File(\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)

I've seen references to rEFInd being used. This package is not installed. Can I just install that on the running system or do I need a clean installation? I'd prefer to keep the ability to run MacOS, though I don't normally need it.
The problem I'm trying to resolve is waking the iMac/Mint from suspend, as described here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=335072

I do not know Mac, but they were the first to convert to EFI, now UEFI. I do not think they even have legacy/BIOS/CSM mode as that is another chip on motherboard. Microsoft allowed the old BIOS mode with UEFI as many large customers had older PC but wanted newer Windows for compatibility. New PCs starting about 2020 are now also UEFI only. The rEFInd boot manager should be something you can just install, but always have good backups. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/  I though best to keep MacOS in case system needs updates.

You do not give enough information. What did you search for? Why? What answer did you find, where?

Yes, MacOS (or Mac OS X as it may have been in 2008) never needed BIOS... but remember that Macs also had Boot Camp for booting contemporary versions of Windows, which did not support EFI at that time. That means, any Macs with Boot Camp support for pre-UEFI versions of Windows must have had at least minimal BIOS support.
Yes, you can just install the rEFInd package.
Although rEFInd has the ability to optionally switch Macs to legacy BIOS mode at boot time, it is still just an (U)EFI bootloader: you may have to install a BIOS version of GRUB or some other BIOS-mode bootloader to handle the rest of the boot process after rEFInd is used to trigger the switch.
